# Debug Program option in Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7

I noticed that in Windows 7, unlike XP, if a program crashes that I am debugging in Visual Studio 2008, I don't get the option to Debug the program.  Rather, it just says that the program crashed and Microsoft is looking for a solution.

Right now, if my program throws an exception, I can't return back to the debugging session in VS 2008, the program just quits.  Is there a way around this?

EDIT: 
Here is what the old debug window looked like in XP, but I can't get this in Win7 and can't debug my program now:

[image: debug window]
<sub>(source: [scalemax.com](http://www.scalemax.com/tlsupport/Crash_files/image006.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that if you click to send the error to MS, it finally gives you a Debug option.

Also, if you go into Control Panel->Action Center->Change Action Center Settings->Problem Report Settings and change the radio selection to "Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions" you get the Debug option right away.

One big issue I notice is that it won't debug with the debugger that is already attached.  It makes you create a new debugger instance in VS 2008 and then complains there is already a debugger attached...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have  a Windows 7 installation, so I can't say if there is another mechanism at work, but the obvious answer is to check if Just In Time debugging is turned on in VS (Tools/Options/Debugging/Just In Time).

Comment: It is turned on for all options.  Thank you though.